# Can I remove the var leastPricedOffer in the official Google in-app demo project?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A comes from the official Google in-app demo [project](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/main/PlayBillingCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/sample/subscriptionscodelab/ui/MainViewModel.kt).

I think that `var leastPricedOffer` is NOT NECESSARY in Code A, so I modify it as Code B, is Code B right?

**Code A**

```
private fun leastPricedOfferToken(
        offerDetails: List<ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails>
    ): String {
        var offerToken = String()
        var leastPricedOffer: ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails
        var lowestPrice = Int.MAX_VALUE

        if (!offerDetails.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            for (offer in offerDetails) {
                for (price in offer.pricingPhases.pricingPhaseList) {
                    if (price.priceAmountMicros < lowestPrice) {
                        lowestPrice = price.priceAmountMicros.toInt()
                        leastPricedOffer = offer
                        offerToken = leastPricedOffer.offerToken
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return offerToken
    }
```

**Code B**

```
private fun leastPricedOfferToken(
        offerDetails: List<ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails>
    ): String {
        var offerToken = String()       
        var lowestPrice = Int.MAX_VALUE

        if (offerDetails.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (offer in offerDetails) {
                for (price in offer.pricingPhases.pricingPhaseList) {
                    if (price.priceAmountMicros < lowestPrice) {
                        lowestPrice = price.priceAmountMicros.toInt()                       
                        offerToken = offer.offerToken
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return offerToken
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the `var leastPricedOffer` in Code A and use Code B instead. The variable `leastPricedOffer` in Code A is indeed redundant, used only to temporarily store the `offer` object, which is then used to get the `offerToken`.

In Code B, you directly assign the `offerToken` without the need for an intermediate variable.

Note that a better name for `offerToken` would be `lowestPricedOfferToken`: That does reflects more accurately its purpose in the context of the function: it is not just any offer token, but specifically the token of the offer with the lowest price.

```kotlin
private fun leastPricedOfferToken(
        offerDetails: List<ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails>
    ): String {
    var lowestPricedOfferToken = String()       
    var lowestPrice = Int.MAX_VALUE

    // Iterate through each offer and its prices
    if (offerDetails.isNotEmpty()) {
        for (offer in offerDetails) {
            for (price in offer.pricingPhases.pricingPhaseList) {
                // Update the lowestPricedOfferToken if a lower price is found
                if (price.priceAmountMicros < lowestPrice) {
                    lowestPrice = price.priceAmountMicros.toInt()                       
                    lowestPricedOfferToken = offer.offerToken
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return lowestPricedOfferToken
}
```